# Clear NavigationBar with NO translucent

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to create a **clear** UINavigationBar class with `isTranslucent = false` ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to change properties of `UINavigationController` on the `viewDidLoad` method of your `viewController` as follows :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let nav = self.navigationController {
        nav.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        nav.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        nav.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already the solution with `isTranslucent = true`, I was wondering if is possible to achieve the same result with `isTranslucent = false`.